# hibernate updating child table instead of appending records to child table

Tags: java, hibernate

@Antoniossss

The records are getting inserted into Wslog table but erroring out for Emp. It is also trying to insert the object wslog.

```
insert into wslog (totrecords, logid) values (?, ?)
insert into emp (sid, logid,  **wslog**, eid, ename) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
```

**WsLog(Primary)**

```
@Column(name = "logid") //has sequence
private long logid;
@Column(name = "totrecords")
private long totrecords;
@OneToMany(mappedBy="wslog") 
private List<Emps> emplist;
```

**Emps(Child)**

```
    @Id
    @Column(name = "sid") //has sequence
    private long sid;
    @Column(name = "logid")
    private long logid;
    @Column(name = "eid")
    private Long eid;
    @Column(name = "ename")
    private String ename;
    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "logid")
    private Wslog wslog;
```

Repositiory

```
 public interface WsLogRepository extends CrudRepository<WsLog, Long> {

 }
```

Service Implementation

```
    my.domain.client.model.Wslog wsLog = new Wslog();
    wsLog.setTotrecords(getTotrecords());
    List<my.domain.client.model.Employees> empList = new ArrayList<my.domain.client.model.Employees>();
    for (my.domain.client.model.Employees emp : getEmployees()) {
        my.domain.client.model.Employees emps = new Employees();            
        emps.setID(getEid());
        emps.setEname(getEname());
        emps.setLog(wsLog);
        empList.add(emps);
    }
    wsLog.setEmployees(empList);
    wsLogRepository.save(wsLog);
```

Comment: which column is your primary key in emp table ?

Comment: And why would you set `LogId` insteed of `Log` object is another mistery

Answer (score 0):

Your mapping is wrong,

**EMP**

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "logid")
private WsLog log;
```

**WsLog**

```
@OneToManny(mappedBy="log)
private List<Emp> employees;
```

And this is how you make relation

```
Employee emp=new  Employee();
emp.setLog(log); // log is of type WsLog ofcourse
```

You dont set manually ids etc.
Also r emember to use `@Id` annotation on identifiers fields.

Comment: I am still having issues. I have modified my main POST with updated code.